# How to center-justify a string in text file using fprintf in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am writing an output file to MATLAB as part of a report. I need to center justify the title which is having a fixed column width.

If I use the below code it becomes right-justified.

```
fprintf(fileID,'%50s \r\n', 'Balance Sheet')
```

And if I use the below code it becomes left-justified.

```
fprintf(fileID,'%-50s \r\n', 'Balance Sheet')
```

But how do I center-justify?

Comment: Thank you Steve. Yes, this helps but I was wondering if there is more direct command as I believe this ought to be of a standard use for which an option might be available in the library.

Comment: Not aware of one, but if you know what the maximum width should be (50 here?) then it should be pretty straightforward to write your own function with `length()`

Comment: See: [`strjust`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjust.html)

Comment: strjust is only applied with in a cell in MATLAB

Comment: That's [not true](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjust.html#inputarg_txt).