# string - num2str auto width format in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, center

Sorry for my dumb question, i'm new on matlab.
I have an matrix array like this

```
num = [
    4.2, 3, 5;
    3, 12.1, 3.4;
    2, 5.22, 4
]
```

I just want to display it using center align format, like the example below

[image]

but number in **num** array is dynamic, sometimes on each row contain up to 4 or more number like this

```
num = [
    4.2, 3, 5, 7.899;
    3, 12.1, 3.4, 89;
    2, 5.22, 4, 9.1
]
```

I was trying using **num2str()** function, but it doesn't fit on my case because my data is dynamic (sometimes it always have 2 or 3 more digit of decimal number) here is my code:

```
num2str('%10.1f \t %10.1f \t %10.1f \n', num);
```

Is there any other function beside using num2str(), because my array data is dynamic

Comment: What are you displaying it in? Just printing it out? If you use e.g. a `uitable` control, I bet you can center the text using the display settings of the control...

Comment: Can you describe exactly what's wrong with the output of `num2str`? Mine looks about right with `sprintf('%10.3g \t %10.3g \t %10.3g \n', num(:,1:3)')`, except the centre align. The question [Centering strings with printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2461667/5358968) might help too

Comment: @Dev-iL I just display it on listbox panel

Comment: @Steve actually there is no problem with the output, i just want to make it center align

Comment: Can you post what you'd like the exact output to look like for the above two cases? (Replace the image with a code block for each)

Comment: I know you already have an answer, but [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484032/3372061) might be related.

Comment: Related: [How to center-justify a string in text file using fprintf in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43034610/5358968)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can centre a string with [`strjust`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjust.html). Here, I build the individual elements in a loop with [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and add a newline character:

```
num = [
4.2, 3, 5, 7.899;
3, 12.1, 3.4, 89;
2, 5.22, 4, 9.1
];

% Loop over rows (ii) and columns (jj) of num
output = '';
for ii = 1:size(num,1)
  for jj = 1:size(num,2)
    output = [output, strjust(sprintf('%10.4g',num(ii,jj)),'center')];
  end % for jj
  output = [output, '\n'];
end % for ii
fprintf(output)
```

Output:

```
   4.2        3         5       7.899   
    3        12.1      3.4        89    
    2        5.22       4        9.1
```

You can put this into e.g. an image by using a final call to `sprintf`:

```
text(0.5, 0.5, sprintf(output))
```

Note that this uses a non-fixed width font, so a long line might not look centre-justified.  This can be seen by using

```
num = [999, 999, 999, 999; 1, 1, 1, 1];
```

MATLAB version R2014a.

Comment: This is work, but have one problem with mine, so i just want to display it on set(handles.gui) is there any other way how to display on it, because when i put set() inside for loop, it just display the last row

Comment: @JhonnyJr. I've changed it, should be more flexible

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but i still confused, because '\n' operator is on the output too, it doesn't want to generate a new line

Comment: @JhonnyJr. try using your `set` method on `sprintf(output)` instead?

Comment: @JhonnyJr. could be worth searching for other answers along the lines of *using set handles gui with newline*, or posting a new question trying to add `1\n2` to a gui.

Comment: @JhonnyJr. new example using `text` to put it into an image (I've not used any GUI features in MATLAB)

Comment: sprintf is work steve, thanks a lot, but i think when using "text" gui style will make it not look so good

Comment: @JhonnyJr.perhaps my last example is motivation enough for a new question